# How to do edgehovering in sigma.js?

Tags: sigma.js

I have used `enableEdgeHovering: true` but still hovering is not working? I want to show label only on hovering else hide edge label

Comment: Please supply an example of this not working, e.g. by linking to https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
s = new sigma({
          graph: json,
          renderer: {
            container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
            type: 'canvas'
          },
          settings: {
            animationsTime: 1000,
            borderSize: 2,
            outerBorderSize: 3,
            defaultNodeOuterBorderColor: 'rgb(236, 81, 72)',
            enableEdgeHovering: true,
            edgeHoverHighlightNodes: 'circle',
            sideMargin: 1,
            edgeHoverColor: 'edge',
            defaultEdgeHoverColor: '#000',
            edgeHoverSizeRatio: 1,
            edgeHoverExtremities: true,
            scalingMode: 'outside' 
          }
        });
```

use above snippets, this will give you exact output as you want.